# Routing to a new Component based on user login status

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-firebase

I am just getting started with React Native and I am having some trouble wrapping my head around how the framework is built.

My entry point is App.js, I want App.js to just check if a user is logged in / authenticated with firebase. Using firebase on android, once a user is authenticated, their state is saved in the firebase auth object until they manually log out. I am hoping to use the same system in RN.
So I want App.js to just check if a user is authenticated and if yes, send him to the home screen (Homescreen component) or if not send him to log in (Login component).

I also wrote a function that will check if a user is authenticated and route them appropriately.
I am also separately built the navigation container but I have no clue how to link them together.

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View , Image, Button} from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'; 
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import auth, { firebase } from "@react-native-firebase/auth"


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function isTheUserAuthenticated({navigation}) 
{
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    if (user) 
    {
      navigation.navigate('Home')
    } 
    else 
    {
      navigation.navigate('Login')
    }
}

function App() 
{
  isTheUserAuthenticated();
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  titleText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  horizontalContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
});

export default App;
```

HomeScreen.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View , Image, Button} from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'; 
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import auth, { firebase } from "@react-native-firebase/auth"


function HomeScreen() 
{

  return (

    <View style= { [ styles.container, {flexDirection: "column"} ] }>

      <View style={ [ styles.horizontalContainer, {flex: 2} ]  }>
        <Image source={require('./imgs/usdt_logo.png')} />
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>USDT</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={{ flex: 2, backgroundColor: "orange" }} >
      </View>

      <View style={{ flex: 2, backgroundColor: "blue" }} >
      </View>

      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }} >
      </View>

    </View>

  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
    },
    titleText: {
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    horizontalContainer: {
      flexDirection: "row",
    },
  });
  

export default HomeScreen;
```

LoginScreen.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View , Image, Button} from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'; 
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import auth, { firebase } from "@react-native-firebase/auth"


function LoginScreen() 
{
  return (
    <View style= { [ styles.container, {flexDirection: "column"} ] }>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>FUKU</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
    },
    titleText: {
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    horizontalContainer: {
      flexDirection: "row",
    },
  });
  

export default LoginScreen;
```

Also, my HomeScreen.js and LoginScreen.js files are in a subfolder called "pages"

Where should I call my isTheUserAuthenticated and is that function even properly written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is I will always load the Login screen first, then check if Authenticated, navigation.navigate('Home') **or** vice versa.

In addition u can use

```
 <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName = isAuthenticated ? "Home" : "Login"
    >
....
</Stack.Navigator>
```

you can use both together, depending on how you save the state of your login.

Is your isAuthenticated function properly written? The answer is **no**. For firebase auth, you need to watch [onauthstatechange](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

There is an example [here](https://gist.github.com/timc1/d559d0f8769b4badc0bfc22484fe97a3) showing how you should create a Provider/Content, to save your auth state